# Html/css : How to make values in an input field separated by boxes

Tags: html, css

Hi guys i'm trying to design an UI input text field that accepts multiple value and i wan't to separate them by boxes just like when u  add tags when u ask questions here each tags is boxed with "x" button that acts as delete,  i saw also many designs like this but spend how many hours searching on how to do it but didn't see one. Hope someone can give a hint how to do it or what are my needs to do it thanks

Comment: Down voted for what??

Comment: Are you using a single input field. Question is bit messy. Can you update your question with html code?

Comment: @cleverprogrammer1, your requirement is correct but you should keep the button controls with "x" instead TextBox control in a DIV element.

Comment: Yhup a single input field that accepts multiple values e.g 'skills' field that will accepts 'java', 'php' etc. But each input is separated by box i saw many designs like that already

Comment: You get down voted because there shows no effort of your own, with the code you have so far, which also makes it very unclear to understand, and on top of it all (in its current state), it is off topic, being to broad. Take the time to read [ask] and you will avoid down votes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<body>Multiple select example
    <div class="selectRow">       
        <select id="mutliSelectItems" data-placeholder="Select City(s)" multiple>
            <option value="1">Lucknow</option>
            <option value="2">Agra</option>
            <option value="3">Shravasti</option>
            <option value="4">Gorakhpur</option>
            <option value="5">Faizabad</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
```

---

```
.selectRow {
    display : block;
    padding : 20px;
}
.select2-container {
    width: 200px;
}
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#mutliSelectItems").select2();
});
```

---

*In addition to above code please add below libraries*

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js

http://select2.github.io/select2/select2-3.5.1/select2.css

http://select2.github.io/select2/select2-3.5.1/select2.js

**My fiddle:** [working fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/e6j971um/6/)

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use bootstrap tags-input like

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput.css">


<input type="text" value="html,input,tag" data-role="tagsinput"></input>

<script>
$('input').tagsinput({
  typeahead: {
    source: function(query) {
      return $.getJSON('citynames.json');
    }
  }
});
</script>
```